# make two local nodejs servers req and res to each other

Tags: node.js, server

Learning some basics about req and res between nodejs servers.

Want server 1 to send a `get` to server2

server 1:

```
var http = require('http');
http.get("http://localhost:8080/", function(res) {
    console.log("what's going on?")
});
```

server 2:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write(req.url);
    res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);
```

to some experienced ones, this obviously won't work.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
```

what is wrong please and how to make it work?
just some hint would be good.
if you would suggest using 'request' module, please also provide solution without it.

Comment: the first one is actually not a server, it's just a simple request from another file that is run by node server1.js

Comment: I didnt add thumb down and I will consider your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out why.. in fact there wasn't any problem with the code. 
it's the timing of nodemon,
two .js files were placed in the same folder and changing one cause two nodemon to restart, 
which the request was made to 8080, the server is being restarted and won't be able to respond...